# Docker-machine does not shows up on Virtual Box?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have installed docker machine and it shows up running when I check using the `docker-machine ls` command. But it does not ends up creating a default VM on my virtual box.

The logs generated are as under:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /root/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /root/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...

This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not
reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as
the Docker daemon port (usually <ip>:2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using.
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env default
root@varun:~# docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.09.0-ce
```

What changes should I do so that the docker machine gets created as a VM on Virtual Box also?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the Hyper-V virtual switch and reference it

docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "NameOfVirtualSwitch" nameOfNode

Please refer the documenation.
<https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#4-create-the-nodes-with-docker-machine-and-the-microsoft-hyper-v-driver>

Comment: The command makes an assumption that the docker cloud is in swarm mode and uses the manager or worker as nameOfNode. In my case it is not using the swarm mode